# Transmission lines...which one is high? potential or potential difference?

Tags: electricity, electric-current

The electric potential at generating station is 11,000 V...why such high potential is generated there?
From generating station it is transferred to local station...is there any electric potential at the local station?
If not,then a lot of current would flow ..isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Electricity is distributed at high voltage to minimise losses through heating. The amount of power lost through heating is  $P_{loss} = P_{total}^2 R / V^2$. One can use a transformer to change a high current, low voltage signal to a low current, high voltage signal.

At the receiving station, this is converted back to lower voltage for distribution by reversing the process.

In principle, if the high voltage is shorted to ground, a lot of current will flow. This is why touching a high voltage line would be very bad for you! But the power station will quickly regulate such a short, so it will be rather short-lived.